# Merge multiple flat associative arrays and sum the values of shared keys

Tags: php, arrays, sum, merging-data

I am looking for an `array_merge()` function that does NOT replace values, but ADDS them.

Example, this is the code I am trying:

```
echo "<pre>"; 

$a1 = array(
     "a" => 2
    ,"b" => 0
    ,"c" => 5
);

$a2 = array(
     "a" => 3
    ,"b" => 9
    ,"c" => 7
    ,"d" => 10
);

$a3 = array_merge($a1, $a2);
print_r($a3);
```

Sadly, this outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 3
    [b] => 9
    [c] => 7
    [d] => 10
)
```

I then tried, instead of `array_merge`, just simply adding the two arrays

```
$a3 = $a1 + $a2;
```

But this outputs

```
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [b] => 0
    [c] => 5
    [d] => 10
)
```

What I truly want is to be able to pass as many arrays as needed, and then get their sum. So in my example, I want the output to be:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 5
    [b] => 9
    [c] => 12
    [d] => 10
)
```

Of course I can schlepp and build some function with many `foreach` etc, but am looking or a smarter, cleaner solution.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing you want to write a function for. I wouldn't consider it "schlepping" by any means, this is a fairly unique thing to want to do. I could be proven wrong however, but I don't believe there's any native function that can handle this by itself. If writing a function is the solution, do you still need help?

Comment: I believe there is no built-in function that can do this, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/php-how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key

Comment: The question is formulated wrong. `array_merge` does *merge two arrays while retaining **all** keys*. But you want to *sum the **value** of identical keys of two arrays*, which is something else.

Comment: [merge/sum multi dimentional array php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44607229/6521116)

Answer (score 70):

```
$sums = array();
foreach (array_keys($a1 + $a2) as $key) {
    $sums[$key] = (isset($a1[$key]) ? $a1[$key] : 0) + (isset($a2[$key]) ? $a2[$key] : 0);
}
```

You *could* shorten this to the following using the error suppression operator, but it should be considered ugly:

```
$sums = array();
foreach (array_keys($a1 + $a2) as $key) {
    $sums[$key] = @($a1[$key] + $a2[$key]);
}
```

Alternatively, some mapping:

```
$keys = array_fill_keys(array_keys($a1 + $a2), 0);
$sums = array_map(function ($a1, $a2) { return $a1 + $a2; }, array_merge($keys, $a1), array_merge($keys, $a2));
```

Or sort of a combination of both solutions:

```
$sums = array_fill_keys(array_keys($a1 + $a2), 0);
array_walk($sums, function (&$value, $key, $arrs) { $value = @($arrs[0][$key] + $arrs[1][$key]); }, array($a1, $a2));
```

I think these are concise enough to adapt one of them on the spot whenever needed, but to put it in terms of a function that accepts an unlimited number of arrays and sums them:

```
function array_sum_identical_keys() {
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    $keys = array_keys(array_reduce($arrays, function ($keys, $arr) { return $keys + $arr; }, array()));
    $sums = array();

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $sums[$key] = array_reduce($arrays, function ($sum, $arr) use ($key) { return $sum + @$arr[$key]; });
    }
    return $sums;
}
```

Comment: Now why was this voted down, please? It may look cryptic, but only if you're not used to thinking in sets and functions. IMO it's a lot more elegant than nested loops or tons of `if`s.

Comment: Third solution reseted array keys for me.

Comment: Why we are checking like `(isset($a1[$key]) ? $a1[$key] : 0)` in 1st function? Can we directly do like `$a1[$key] + $a2[$key]` in that function like 2nd function?

Comment: @viren To avoid *undefined index* notices if both arrays don’t contain the same keys. In the second version we use the error suppression operator instead for that purpose.

Answer (score 16):

My contribution:

```
function array_merge_numeric_values()
{
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    $merged = array();
    foreach ($arrays as $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if ( ! is_numeric($value))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if ( ! isset($merged[$key]))
            {
                $merged[$key] = $value;
            }
            else
            {
                $merged[$key] += $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```

Pass as many arrays to it as you want. Feel free to add some more defense, ability to accept multidimensional arrays, or type checking.

Demo: http://codepad.org/JG6zwAap

Answer (score 6):

its not so complicate
do something like:

```
$a3 = $a1;

foreach($a2 as $k => $v) {
    if(array_key_exists($k, $a3)) {
       $a3[$k] += $v;
    } else {
       $a3[$k] = $v; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a script which can receive an indeterminant number of arrays, then `array_merge_recursive()` will squeeze them together nicely.  Just understand that if a key only occurs once, then its value will remain a scalar value -- this means that before calling `array_sum()` all values should be explicitly cast to array-type to avoid breakage.  Because `array_map()` is only receiving one array as input, it will preserve the associative keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TI2VI))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => array_sum((array) $v),
        array_merge_recursive($a1, $a2, $a3)
    )
);
```

---

To handle your two input arrays:

You could use `array_reduce()` if you wish for a functional iterator which returns the new array, but it's a little noisy. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/daJEH)) ([Demo before arrow functions](https://3v4l.org/U4bGs))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_keys($a2),
        fn($result, $k) => array_merge($result, [$k => ($result[$k] ?? 0) + $a2[$k]]),
        $a1
    )
);
```

Otherwise, I recommend the clarity and brevity of a classic `foreach()` loop. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/piO0q))

```
$result = $a1;
foreach ($a2 as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = ($result[$k] ?? 0) + $v;
}
var_export($result);
```