# add the values of two different associative arrays in php . display unique key-values too in the result array

Tags: php, associative-array, array-merge

i need to merge two associative arrays which may or may not contain same key,if key is same the values need to added and stored in the resultant array

```
 $array1 = array(
      'a' => 5,
      'b' => 10,
      'c' => 6,
      'k' = > 10
    );

$array2 = array(
  'a' => 100,
  'c' => 200,
  'd' => 30,
  'k' => 10
);
```

how to add the above two associative arrays and receive the following output/associative array -

```
 $array2 = array(
      'a' => 105,
      'b' => 10,
      'c' => 206,
      'd' => 30,
      'k' => 20
    );
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086267/how-to-merge-two-arrays-by-summing-the-merged-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 $array1 = array(
      'a' => 5,
      'b' => 10,
      'c' => 6,
      'k' => 10
    );

$array2 = array(
  'a' => 100,
  'c' => 200,
  'd' => 30,
  'k' => 10
);

$sums = array();
foreach (array_keys($array1 + $array2) as $key) {
    $sums[$key] = (isset($array1[$key]) ? $array1[$key] : 0) + (isset($array2[$key]) ? $array2[$key] : 0);
}

print_r($sums);
```

Comment: Works fine...Thanks a lot !! ...However,could you plz explain a bit about the following part-
(isset($array1[$key]) ? $array1[$key] : 0)

Comment: If you think it works you should accept his answer Mayur

Comment: @antony--i accept Tamil Selvan's answer...just wanted a little explaination about (isset($array1[$key]) ? $array1[$key] : 0) as I am new to PHP and also programming.

Comment: @Mayur You haven't accepted it. You have to click on the tick.
If you want to learn about shorthand conditional statements then ask another question or read here http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples.

Comment: Gentlemen,its accepted now...!!! (m new to stackoverflow.com,so dint know..SORRY)

Answer (score 1):

for finding unique index value

```
$array2 =array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

and for finding unique value you can try

```
$array2 =array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a3 = array_merge_recursive ($array1, $array2);
foreach ($a3 as $key => $value)
{
    $a3[$key] = (is_array($value))?array_sum($value):$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do this with an internal function but it is doable by simply iterating through both arrays.

```
function merge_add($array1, $array2)
{
    $result = array();
    merge_add_array($array1, $result);
    merge_add_array($array2, $result);
    return $result;
}

function merge_add_array($array, &$result)
{
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $result))
        {
            $result[$key] += $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}

$result = merge_add($array1, $array2);
```

The `&` will cause [passing by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
      'a' => 5,
      'b' => 10,
      'c' => 6,
      'k' => 10
    );

$array2 = array(
  'a' => 100,
  'c' => 200,
  'd' => 30,
  'k' => 10
);

$keys = array_keys($array1 + $array2);

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $array2[$key] = isset($array1[$key]) && isset($array2[$key]) ? ($array1[$key] + $array2[$key]) : (isset($array1[$key]) ? $array1[$key] : $array2[$key]);
}

print_r($array2);
```