# Compare values between two multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have PHP code below that will check for two associative arrays. My problem is that, this code perform many loops and I don't want it cause it affects the performance of my application. Is there any way or function in PHP that will automatically detect for duplicate? And result with the same as mine.

Please check sample [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cec307bd4ca79eeb56e57397bbb5fe2d06a842ce).

Here is my code:

```
// first Array
$m1Array = array();
$m1Array[] = array('eId' => '0001', 'numVal' => 1);
$m1Array[] = array('eId' => '0002', 'numVal' => 2);
$m1Array[] = array('eId' => '0003', 'numVal' => 3);
$m1Array[] = array('eId' => '0004', 'numVal' => 4);
$m1Array[] = array('eId' => '0005', 'numVal' => 5);
$m1Array[] = array('eId' => '0006', 'numVal' => 6);

//second Array
$m2Array = array();
$m2Array[] = array('eId' => '0001', 'numVal' => 1);
$m2Array[] = array('eId' => '0004', 'numVal' => 4);
$m2Array[] = array('eId' => '0005', 'numVal' => 5);
$m2Array[] = array('eId' => '0006', 'numVal' => 6);
$m2Array[] = array('eId' => '0007', 'numVal' => 7);

//final result array
$finalResult = array();


//[seond array] will be my master or the bases
//loop thru the [second array(m2Array)]
foreach($m2Array as $m2Arr){

    $numValSum  = 0;
    $dupFound   = false;

    //get current eId value in [second array]
    $eId2 = $m2Arr['eId'];

    //loop thru the [first array(m1Array)] to check if eId2 has duplicate
    $arrIndex = 0;
    foreach($m1Array as $m1Arr){

        //get current eId value in [first array]
        $eId1 = $m1Arr['eId'];

        //check if the value of eId2 is equal to eId 1
        if($eId1 == $eId2){
            //if equal then
            //add their respective numVal value and put it to [final result array]
            $numValSum      = $m2Arr['numVal'] + $m1Arr['numVal'];
            $finalResult[]  = array('eId' => $eId2, 'numValSum' => $numValSum);

            unset($m1Array[$arrIndex]); //remove the duplicate eId in [first array]
            sort($m1Array);             //sort the index of [first array]

            $dupFound   = true;
        }

    $arrIndex += 1;
    }

    //if eId2 has no duplicate then just add the numVal to [final result array]
    if($dupFound == false){
        $finalResult[]  = array('eId' => $eId2, 'numValSum' => $m2Arr['numVal']);
    }

}

//now check if [second array] still have an element
//if still have then add all to [final result array]
if(count($m1Array)){
    foreach($m1Array as $m1Arr){
        $finalResult[]  = array('eId' =>  $m1Arr['eId'], 'numValSum' => $m1Arr['numVal']);
    }
}


//display my final result array
foreach($finalResult as $fRes){
   echo $fRes['eId'].' -> '.$fRes['numValSum'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Additional Info.:

Apologies, but I think some of you missed the point of my code. I don't want to remove duplicates in my arrays. The code will check for duplicate bet. two arrays and if the `eId` has a duplicate in another array then add their corresponding `numVal` before puting it to my `output` or `finalResult array`. But if don't have duplicate then put it directly to my `finalResult array`.

I attached a table diagram image of how it works. Hope this helps. Thank you.

[image: here]

Comment: This looks like the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086267/how-to-merge-two-arrays-by-summing-the-merged-values

Comment: No it's not. Co'z in my case, I'm not looking for duplicate keys. I'm looking for the duplicate value inside my `eId` key and adds the value of `numVal` key. But still, maybe this will help me. I'll try to check some suggestion and try to apply it in my code. Thank you.

Comment: so when the value matches -- you sum it. Then what you do when it does not match?

Comment: As shown in my diagram it will go directly to my `finalResult` array. By the way @Aniket already gave me the shorter code. I think that's the code I'm looking for. I just want to make my code shorter and cleaner. Thank you so much for your time @sevavietl. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the `59` lines of code to `3` by using [`array_udiff()`](http://php.net/array_udiff) to get the difference between two multidimensional arrays. It accepts a function for data comparision:

```
var_dump(array_udiff($m1Array, $m2Array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a["eId"] - $b["eId"];
}));
```

There is no such function in php, so you can break it down to pieces:

```
$finalResult = $a1 = array_column($m1Array, "numVal", "eId");
$a2 = array_column($m2Array, "numVal", "eId");

array_walk($finalResult, function(&$item, $key) use ($a2) {
    if(isset($a2[$key])) $item += $a2[$key];
});

$finalResult = array_merge($finalResult, array_diff_key($a2, $finalResult));
// Array ( [0001] => 2 [0002] => 2 [0003] => 3 [0004] => 8 [0005] => 10 [0006] => 12 [0007] => 7 )
```

Comment: Hello @Aniket. Thank you for your answer but i think `array_udiff()` will just remove the duplicate item. I edit my question above so that it will be more clearer. Hope that helps. Thanks!

Comment: @Jun There is no direct alternative for it. I have edited my answer to suit your needs, you can rearrange the values according to your requirements.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for!!! :) Thank you so much @Aniket. Appreciate your time!

Comment: @Jun Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use hash tables. Instead of having a list of objects, use `eId` as a key as well, in this way you can avoid nesting loops and only lookup for keys, like:

```
$allKeys = array_unique( array_merge( array_keys($m1Array), array_keys($m2Array) ) );

foreach ($allKeys as $k) {
   if (isset($m1Array[$k]) and isset($m2Array[$k]) ) {
      // duplicate
   }  
}
```