# Merge two "m-Y"-keyed arrays and sum the values of intersecting keys, then sort by year then month

Tags: php, arrays, merge, sum, associative-array

I want to merge two associative arrays and sum their values where both arrays have the same key.

```
$first = [
    '01-1970' => 0.00,
    '03-2019' => 4350.00,
    '05-2019' => 150.00,
    '06-2019' => 50.00,
];

$second = [
    '03-2019' => 0.00,
    '04-2019' => 0.00,
    '06-2019' => 34.83,
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    '01-1970' => 0.00,
    '03-2019' => 4350,
    '04-2019' => 0.00,
    '05-2019' => 150.00,
    '06-2019' => 84.83,
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array sum of value based on same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286749/array-sum-of-value-based-on-same-key)

Comment: @MayankVadiya the arrays have different keys. ..

Comment: @treyBake he want to sum of same keys, check is expected  output

Comment: @MayankVadiya true-  but the array to merge isn't the same key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_keys` to get the unique from both of the array and then loop through keys to some them

```
$r = [];
$keys = array_keys($a1+$a2);
foreach($keys as $v){
  $r[$v] = (empty($a1[$v]) ? 0 : $a1[$v]) + (empty($a2[$v]) ? 0 : $a2[$v]);
}
```

[Working DEMO](https://3v4l.org/3rVT7)

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to loop the arrays individually, and sum up the values into a resulting array as you go. We can create a new array that contains the two arrays them to shorten our code a bit (see how we define `[$first, $second]` as the first loop).

This removes any problems with mixed lengths, and keeps all the keys and values in the array intact.

```php
$result = [];
// Loop over our two arrays, here called $first and $second
foreach ([$first, $second] as $a) {
    // Loop over the values in each array
    foreach ($a as $k=>$v) {
        // If the index is new to the $result array, define it to be zero (to avoid undefined index notices) 
        if (!isset($result[$k]))
            $result[$k] = 0;

        // Sum up the value!
        $result[$k] += $v;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/X4ijP

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a function I made:

```
<?php
    function array_sum_multi($arrayOne, $arrayTwo)
    {
        # get rid of keys
        $valuesOne = array_values($arrayOne);
        $valuesTwo = array_values($arrayTwo);

        //create return array
        $output = [];

        # loop that shizzle
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($valuesOne); $i++)
        {
            $output[$i] = $valuesOne[$i] + (!empty($valuesTwo[$i]) ? $valuesTwo[$i] : 0);
        }

        return $output;
    }

    $result = array_sum_multi([0.00, 4350.00, 150.00, 50.00], [0.00, 0.00, 34.83]);

    # then for your keys:
    $result = array_combine(array_keys($yourFirstArray), $result);

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($result, 1) .'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $first_array; // just copy array into result

// scan second array
foreach ($second_array as $k => $v) {
   // if key already exists, then add, else just set
   $result[$k] = isset($result[$k]) ? ($result[$k] + $v) : $v;
}

// done
print_r($result);
```

Comment: You probably ment to print `$result`, and not `$second_array`? :-) Of all the "fixed two arrays" answers, this is the most elegant way, imo (my answer is a tad more dynamic and can handle more than 2 arrays, so that's the difference there). +1

Comment: @Qirel yes, you're right. That should be `$result`. Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the answer. This one can handle more than 2 arrays too. All what needed is to repeat `foreach` part for each next array. The result will be the sum of all of them

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to implement it would be to loop through each array, and add it to a common array with the same key.

Looping through only one array would result in a lack of a few elements if the first array is smaller than the second one or if some element from the second array are not present in the first one.

So let's just loop through both of them and add it to sum.

```
$sum = [];

foreach($firstArray as $key => $value){
  $sum[$key] = $value + (isset($sum[$key]) ? $sum[$key] : 0.0);
}
foreach($secondArray as $key => $value){
  $sum[$key] = $value + (isset($sum[$key]) ? $sum[$key] : 0.0);
}

print_r($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method thank you,

```
$sum = [];
foreach($firstArray as $key => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($key,$secondArray)){
        $newArray = [$key=>$value+$secondArray[$key]]; 
        $sum = array_merge($sum,$newArray);
    }else{
        $newArray = [$key=>$value]; 
        $sum = array_merge($sum,$newArray);
    }
}

//your final required result
var_dump($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate over the first array if because by definition all of its keys will be guaranteed to be unique. Directly save the first array to the result.

Then iterate over the second array and add its values to corresponding jeys in the result array or merely store the element if the key is new to the result.

If you need your "little-endian" keys to be sorted, use `uksort()` and reformat the keys to be "big-endian".

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SXI6Br))

```
$result = $first;
foreach ($second as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = ($result[$k] ?? 0) + $v;
}
uksort(
    $result,
    fn($a, $b) => preg_replace('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', '$2-$1', $a)
                  <=>
                  preg_replace('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', '$2-$1', $b)
);
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
$a1 = array (
        '01-1970' => 0.00,
        '03-2019' => 4350.00,
        '05-2019' => 150.00,
        '06-2019' => 50.00
    );

$a2 = array (
        '03-2019' => 0.00,
        '04-2019' => 0.00,
        '06-2019' => 34.83
    );

$sums = array();
foreach (array_keys($a1 + $a2) as $key) {
    $sums[$key] = @($a1[$key] + $a2[$key]);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($sums);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086267/how-to-merge-two-arrays-by-summing-the-merged-values) is some other solution you can use.

Cheer!

Answer (score -2):

```
$sumArray = [];

foreach($firstArray as $key => $value) {
    $sumArray[$key] = $value + ($secondArray[$key] ?? 0);
}
```

Comment: answers should have explanations so the OP and future visitors can learn

Comment: This snippet will miss unique keys from the second array.