# PHP arrays: summing values with matching dates

Tags: php, arrays

i'm trying to figure out how to sum certain values of a multi-dimensional array if they have similar dates.

Here's my array:

```
<?$myArray=array(

array(
        'year' => 2011,
        'month ' => 5,
        'day' => 13,
        'value' => 2
    ),
array(
        'year' => 2011,
        'month '=> 5,
        'day' => 14,
        'value' => 5
    ),
array(
        'year' => 2011,
        'month ' => 5,
        'day' => 13,
        'value' => 1
    ),
array(
        'year' => 2011,
        'month ' => 5,
        'day' => 14,
        'value' => 9
    )
);?>
```

here's how i'd like the output to look:

```
<?$output=array(

array(
        'year' => 2011,
        'month ' => 5,
        'day' => 13,
        'value' => 3 //the sum of 1+2
    ),
array(
        'year' => 2011,
        'month '=> 5,
        'day' => 14,
        'value' => 14 //the sum of 5+9
    )
);?>
```

Notice how the 4 sub-arrays were matched on `year/month/day` and then only the `value` was summed. I've seen other [SO threads on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/php-how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key) but can't find one where only the `value` is summed and not the `year/month/day` values too.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's much simpler if you just use DateTime objects.

Comment: @MrAzulay thanks can you show me/send a link for how the array matching/summing would look like using DateTime objects? I'll update my question to include this possible alternate format for `$myArray`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be easiest to initially index your output array with a combination of the year/month/day:

**Note**: Your example array above has all its `month` keys with a trailing space.  I'm just using `month` here with *no* trailing space.

```
// Initialize output array...
$out = array();

// Looping over each input array item
foreach ($myArray as $elem) {
  // Initialize a new element in the output keyed as yyyy-mm-dd if it doesn't already exist
  if (!isset($out[$elem['year'] . "-" . $elem['month '] . "-" . $elem['day']])) {
    $out[$elem['year'] . "-" . $elem['month '] . "-" . $elem['day']] = array(
      // Set the date keys...
      'year' => $elem['year'],
      'month' => $elem['month '],
      'day' => $elem['day'],
      // With the current value...
      'value' => $elem['value']
    );
  }
  // If it already exists, just add the current value onto it...
  else {
     $out[$elem['year'] . "-" . $elem['month '] . "-" . $elem['day']]['value'] += $elem['value'];
  }
}

// Now your output array is keyed by date.  Use array_values() to strip off those keys if it matters:
$out = array_values($out);
```

#### Outputs (before calling `array_values()`):

```
array(2) {
  '2011-5-13' =>
  array(4) {
    'year' =>
    int(2011)
    'month' =>
    int(5)
    'day' =>
    int(13)
    'value' =>
    int(3)
  }
  '2011-5-14' =>
  array(4) {
    'year' =>
    int(2011)
    'month' =>
    int(5)
    'day' =>
    int(14)
    'value' =>
    int(14)
  }
}
```

#### Update:

To do the same thing with single-key dates (rather than 3-parts) it is easier without the concatenation:

```
$myArray=array(
      array(
            'date' => '2011-05-13',
            'value' => 2
        ),
    array(
            'date' => '2011-05-14',
            'value' => 5
        ),
        array(
            'date' => '2011-05-13',
            'value' => 7
        ),
    array(
            'date' => '2011-05-14',
            'value' => 3
        ),

);

   foreach ($myArray as $elem) {
      // Initialize a new element in the output if it doesn't already exist
      if (!isset($out[$elem['date']])) {
        $out[$elem['date'] = array(
          // Set the date keys...
          'date' => $elem['date'],
          // With the current value...
          'value' => $elem['value']
        );
      }
      else {
        $out[$elem['date']]['value'] += $elem['value'];
      }
    }
```

Comment: -@Michael, thanks following @MrAzulay's suggestion i can reformat the date's like this `yyyy-mm-dd` if this makes it easier (the sub-array only contains 2 and not 4 key-value pairs).

Comment: @DainisAbols I fixed the double `[[` bracket already. copy/paste error

Comment: I tested your code and got this `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in C:\data\test.php on line 40`. That's at `$out[[$elem['year'] . "-" . $elem['month'] . "-" . $elem['day']] = array(`

Comment: @timpeterson Then the same pattern works, just don't use all the complicated concatenation to build the array key. Just `$out[$elem['date']]`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski ok i can't quite get it, look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/3488345. I'd like to keep the $myArray array structure but this code doesn't do it. There should be only 2 sub-arrays in the `$out` array.

Comment: @timpeterson You are missing the part of my algorithm where it first checks if the key in `$out` already exists. If it already exists, add to it, otherwise create it with the current value. You are appending each of $myArray onto $out.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, awesome, now i understand!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. The result will be in `$newArray` with datetime objects as keys. If you just want it as an indexed array it should be pretty easy to do.

```
// Example array
$myArray = array(
    array(
    'date' => new DateTime('1993-08-11'),
    'value' => 3
    ),

    array(
    'date' => new DateTime('1993-08-11'),
    'value' => 5
    )
);

$newArray = array();

foreach($myArray as $element)
{
    $iterationValue = $element['value'];
    $iterationDate = $element['date'];
    $dateKey = $iterationDate->format('Y-m-d');

    if(array_key_exists($dateKey, $newArray))
    {
        // If we've already added this date to the new array, add the value
        $newArray[$dateKey]['value'] += $iterationValue;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise create a new element with datetimeobject as key
        $newArray[$dateKey]['date'] = $iterationDate;
        $newArray[$dateKey]['value'] = $iterationValue;
    }
}

nl2br(print_r($newArray));
```

Actually ended up doing the pretty much the same thing as @MichaelBerkowski solution. Still, having DateTime objects is always more flexible when you wan't to do things with the dates later in your application.

**Edit: Now tested it and fixed errors**

Comment: -@MrAzulay, thanks for your solution, is `format()` not declared somewhere?

Comment: @timpeterson What do you mean exactly? format() is a method in datetime that converts the date to a string. My first intention was to use the object as the key but I forgot that's not possible in PHP. So I had to make it a string

Comment: oh sorry, missed the `new DateTime('xxxx-xx-xx')` declaration, thought it was just `xxxx-xx-xx`. thanks