# How to Sum the same element from different arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays like this: `array('id'=>value,'id'=>value)`

```
$arrays=array(
    [0] => Array ( [3] => 1, [102] => -1, [15] => 1,)            
    [1] => Array ( [5] => 1, [80] => -1 )                 
    [2] => Array ( [99] => -1, [3] => -1,[5] => 1 ) 
)
```

I need to get the total result of a given key. In the above example, if ask for id of 3, the sum is 0, if ask for id of 5, the sum is 2. I can only think of something like this:

```
  foreach($arrays as $array){
    foreach( $array as $id=>$v){
     if( $id == $asked )
        $total = $total + $v;
    }
  }
```

Somehow I guess there has to be an efficient way to do the job. I would like to learn. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, that's the most efficient method I can think of too. Since you're matching them against nested arrays.

Comment: Check this one out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/php-how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key

Comment: @kech You posted the same comment 3 times.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is make sure $asked exists in the array before looping through it.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about that, I'm working my phone and I submit the comment too many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($arrays as $array) {
    $total += $array[$id];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$key = 3;

$sum = array_reduce($arrays, function(&$memo, $item) use($key){

    array_key_exists($key, $item) && $memo += $item[$key];

    return $memo;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $prec_array=end($arrays);
 foreach($arrays as $array){
    foreach($array as $id=>$v){
     if(array_key_exists($id, $prec_array) )
            $total[$id] += $v + $prec_array[$id] ;
    $prec_array = $array;
    } 
 }
```