# Combine and sum values in multi-dimensional associative array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting, associative

I have an associative array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [amount] => 3
        [name] => Chuck
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [amount] => 2
        [name] => Steve
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [amount] => 5
        [name] =>
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [amount] => 4
        [name] => Chuck
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [amount] =>
        [name] => Chuck
    )
)
```

I need to remove values that are missing a name or amount e.g. [2] and [4] and then sum the totals for each name so that the final array is:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [amount] => 7
        [name] => Chuck
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [amount] => 2
        [name] => Steve
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking for this nowadays, this would be much cleaner:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($data, 'amount'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$starting_array = array( ... ); // Initial array with your setup
$final_array = array();
$sum = 0;

foreach ($starting_array as $idx => $data) {
  if (!empty($data['amount']) && !empty($data['name'])) {
    $final_array[$idx] = $data;
    $sum += $data['amount'];
  }
}

// After looping through all of the items, $final_array should contain all
// of the specific items that have an amount and name set. In addition, the
// total of all of the amounts will be in $sum.
```

Take a look at php's [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). Note: If `0` is an allowed value, you may want to use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks Aiias, that worked for cleaning up the array. What does $idx = $data do? Is this similar to $key = > $value? Also, do you have any advice for summing the values for each name? Thanks again.

Comment: @CameronMacfarlane - In a php `foreach` loop, you loop through all of the items in the array. When you use the syntax `foreach ( $ARRAY as $KEY => $VALUE )` you will get the key of each item and its corresponding value (at that key: e.g. `$ARRAY[$KEY] = $VALUE` for every `$KEY`). I would definitely recommend looking further into php's [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for a more complete explanation. In terms of summing the values for each name, check my edit.

Comment: Hi Aiias, thanks again. I understand how $key => $value works in a foreach loop. I was just asking is $idx=> $data is the same, I have never seen this syntax. Also, I wanted to sum values for each name, opposed to the total of all. I tried the edit, it didn't work for summing the names amount.

Comment: I think I found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195916/associative-array-sum-values-of-the-same-key

Comment: @CameronMacfarlane - Yup, that is definitely another way to do it.