# Array sum the same value of element?

Tags: php

How to sum array the same value of element ?

```
$arr = [
   ['id' => 1, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'a'],
   ['id' => 1, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'a'],
   ['id' => 2, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'b']
];
```

become to :

```
$arr = [
   ['id' => 1, 'qty' => 200, 'name' => 'a'],
   ['id' => 2, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'b']
];
```

i was try but return

> `[ 1=>['qty'=>200], 2=>['qty'=>100] ]`

i was try but return

```
for($i=0; $i<count($cok);$i++){
        $item_id = $cok[$i]['id'];
        $quantity = $cok[$i]['quantity'];
        if (isset($new_items[$item_id])) {
            $new_items[$item_id] = ['quantity' => $new_items[$item_id]['quantity'] + $quantity];
        } else {
            $new_items[$item_id] = ['quantity' => $quantity];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: foreach() loop + basic math

Comment: You can use a map which stores unique keys

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associative array, sum values of the same key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195916/associative-array-sum-values-of-the-same-key)

Comment: thats same return with what i try, but different with what i want

Comment: @DonnyGunawan, you can modify code from selected answer (from Baba) to fit your needs, i would post it as answer, but.... answer already exists... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as pie (:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'a'),
    array('id' => 1, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'a'),
    array('id' => 2, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'b')
);

$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr AS $item) {
  if(isset($new_arr[$item['id']])) {
    $new_arr[$item['id']]['qty'] += $item['qty'];
    continue;
  }

  $new_arr[$item['id']] = $item;
}

$arr = array_values($new_arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dive into my [viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TqEP5b)

And inplace snippet, returns exactly you need:

```
<?
$arr = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'a'),
    array('id' => 1, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'a'),
    array('id' => 2, 'qty' => 100, 'name' => 'b')
);

$ids = array();
foreach ($arr as $i => $subarray) {
    if (!($remove_from_array = array_key_exists($subarray['id'], $ids))) {
        $ids[$subarray['id']] = 0;
    }
    $ids[$subarray['id']] += $subarray['qty'];
    if ($remove_from_array) {
        unset($arr[$i]);
    }
}
foreach ($arr as &$subarray) {
    $subarray['qty'] = $ids[$subarray['id']];
}

print_r($arr);
```