# Associative array, values of the same key: get sums & averages of "sibling" values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, associative-array

I'd like expand on the thread found at [Associative array, sum values of the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195916/associative-array-sum-values-of-the-same-key).

[image: Table]

The OP asks:

> Instead of having the key "Conference" repeating 3 times. I want to
>   have it just once and sum the 3 values into one in order.

The answer given is:

```
 $sum = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
     isset($a[$b['event']]) ? $a[$b['event']]['budget'] += $b['budget'] : $a[$b['event']] = $b;  
     return $a; });
```

I have an associative array with more than two values. I'd like to use a function like the one above, but have it sum **all** key values together, not just 'budget'.
Here is an example that reflects my situation:

The array is as follows:

```
$data = array(
   0 => array(
     'event' => 'Conference',
     'budget' => 3700,
     'people' => 200,
     'rate' => 3000, 
  ),
  1 => array(
    'event' => 'Conference',
    'budget' => 500,
    'people' => 200,
    'rate' => 6000,
  ),
  2 => array(
    'event' => 'Showroom',
    'budget' => 1000,
    'people' => 400,
    'rate' => 30000,
  ),
  3 => array(
    'event' => 'Mission Chez client',
    'budget' => 2000,
    'people' => 200,
    'rate' => 3000,
  ),
  4 => array(
    'event' => 'Séminaire',
    'budget' => 700,
    'people' => 40,
    'rate' => 3000,
  ),
  5 => array(
    'event' => 'Livraison',
    'budget' => 4000,
    'people' => 2,
    'rate' => 3000,
  ),
  6 => array(
    'event' => 'Conference',
    'budget' => 334,
    'people' => 200,
    'rate' => 9000,
  ),
);
```

If I use the code above, I will be able to reduce 'Conference' to one entry, as follows:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [event] => Conference
            [budget] => 4534
            [people] => 200
            [rate] => 5000
        )
```

The budget figure is correct. But the people figure isn't.
How could I get the sum of 'people' as well as 'budget', so that 
[people] => 600?

Finally, is it possible to easily get an **average** value for 'rate'? So, for conference it would be ((3000+6000+9000) / 3 =  6000).

All in all, I'm seeking to organize the table to get a result like:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [event] => Conference  // Key that appears multiple times
                [budget] => 4534  //Sum of all conference budget
                [people] => 600  //Sum of all conference people
                [rate] => 5000  //Average rate of conference
            )
```

Comment: Are you opposed to bringing in a 3rd party library here? Laravel's collections has some methods that would help out with this.

Comment: Fair question. If it has to go the way of 3rd party libraries, then so be it. :) 
But this is for a fairly modest online dashboard project, to be used by only a few partners. So I'd like to only buy shared hosting if possible, to save $$. As I understand it, shared hosting can be limited in terms of what you can install. Hmm... you've got me wondering.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC why do you want to bring a huge cannon for a simple loop? Any 3rd party library in this case won't make it faster unless it is a php extension in C. It only may make it more easily readable but surely not more efficient.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a "huge cannon". That's also why I asked, rather than out right suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 $sum = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
     if (!isset($a[$b['event']])) {
          $a[$b['event']] = $b;
     } else {
         $a[$b['event']]['budget'] += $b['budget'];
         $a[$b['event']]['people'] += $b['people'];
         $a[$b['event']]['rate'] += $b['rate'];
     }
 return $a; });
```

For averages you could try:

```
 $sum = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
     if (!isset($a[$b['event']])) {
          $a[$b['event']] = $b;
          $a[$b['event']]['rate_count'] = 1;
          $a[$b['event']]['average_rate'] = array($b['rate']);
     } else {
         $a[$b['event']]['budget'] += $b['budget'];
         $a[$b['event']]['people'] += $b['people'];
         $a[$b['event']]['rate'] += $b['rate'];
         $a[$b['event']]['rate_count'] += 1;
         $a[$b['event']]['average_rate'] = $a[$b['event']]['rate'] / $a[$b['event']]['rate_count'];
     }
 return $a; });
```