# Sum elements with the same index from two flat arrays with the same element count

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have two arrays:

```
$a = array(10, 2, 5, 10, 0);
$b = array(1, 20, 11, 8, 3);
```

I need to sum up and get the result:

```
$c = array(11, 22, 16, 18, 3);
```

Can I do this without "foreach"?

Comment: You need to add each element of the `$a` to a corresponding element of the array `$b` and get the result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key

Comment: I Used array_merge_recursive() to merge recursively all arrays into one and i splitted every inner arrays using foreach and used array_sum() to sum the inner arrays. Now i have only one array with all arrays added. This is only for arrays with same index!

Comment: It is important for answerers to understand if the two indexed arrays will also have the same size or if one might be longer than the other.

Comment: Since this page is closed, I cannot add an answer with `array_reduce()`. https://3v4l.org/8Efoc ...but I wouldn't use it versus mapped calls of `array_sum()`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

a simple approach could be

```
$c = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

Or if you could use PHP5.6, you could also use variadic functions like this

```
$c = array_map(function (...$arrays) {
    return array_sum($arrays);
}, $a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 22
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 3
)
```

Comment: You don't need PHP 7 for the second approach. Argument unpacking (http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) is available since PHP 5.6.

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php : "The returned array will preserve the keys of the array argument if and only if exactly one array is passed. If more than one array is passed, the returned array will have sequential integer keys." This means that array keys are not preserved.

Comment: My two favourite answers. The variadic solution being my favourite. Indeed, it leads to the next step : appending $a and $b as elements of another array say, $x and then adding ...$x as second argument of array_map. It allows array_map to work with an undefined number of arrays.Not really required but very useful when working with datasets

Answer (score 16):

Try like

```
$c = array();
foreach (array_keys($a + $b) as $key) {
    $c[$key] = $a[$key] + $b[$key];
}
```

Comment: While not specifically asked in this question. This solution (unlike other answers) preserves array keys and even deals with different-length or different-keys arrays

Answer (score 9):

There's no way you can do that without the "foreach" as you asked for, you need to loop on both arrays to get the respective values.

A function using the foreach would be :

```
function sum_arrays($array1, $array2) {
    $array = array();
    foreach($array1 as $index => $value) {
        $array[$index] = isset($array2[$index]) ? $array2[$index] + $value : $value;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Now you just need to do :

```
$c = sum_arrays($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$c = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++) {
  $c[$i] = $a[$i]+$b[$i];
}
```

Comment: As basic as this question and solution may be, please always include some explanation with every answer.  Tell the OP and future researchers how your code works and why it is advisable.