# Sum elements with the same key between two flat arrays with the same number of elements

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have a head array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 10
)
```

And my second array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 7
)
```

Now I want to increase values in my head array by values in the second array.

Result should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 17
)
```

How can I do that?

Patrick.

Comment: A simple loop can do this easily.

Comment: foreach or array_walk with some lambda

Comment: Did you attempt anything and got stuck somewhere? Post your efforts and we 'll be happy to help you.

Comment: I cant find answer for my problem @CodingAnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
$result = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $arr1, $arr2);
```

[`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func_get_args) fetches one element from each array, [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum) adds those two values, and [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) creates the new array. Original idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549249/1438393).

---

Or, if you want to use a loop, try the following:

```
$result = array();

for($i=0,$count=count($arr1); $i < $count; $i++) {
  $result[$i] = $arr1[$i] + $arr2[$i];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 17
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/101207)

Answer (score 2):

The simpler is the better.

```
foreach ($a1 as $index => &$value) {
    $value += $a2[$index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($headArray); $i++)
    $headArray[$i] += $secondArray[$i];
```