# Sum only values which shared a key between two flat arrays (omit value if not in both arrays)

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have two different arrays below:

```
$array1 = [1 => 2, 2 => 3, 6 => 1];
$array2 = [1 => 2, 6 => 2];
```

How can I sum the related values in `$array1` and `$array2` and omit values which do not have a related value?

Desired result:

```
[1 => 4, 6 => 3]
```

Comment: Did you search? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15549249/716691

Comment: What should happen to the elements that do not have a similar key in the other array?

Comment: Well, what's stopping you from doing this? It's a trivial problem and easily solved with a `foreach()`. Are you just being lazy and expecting people to do your work for you?

Comment: This is it YUNOWORK. (Do you get it?)

Comment: @CodeBird That's for summing indexed arrays, not associative arrays.

Comment: @barmar if you look just under the answer I shared, you'll see the same solution as yours. I think people should search a bit, try stuff... Then if it doesn't work, come ask... As it looks the OP neither searched nor tried :) this is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($array2[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = $value + $array2[$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
        $array1[$key] += array2[$key];
    }
}
```