# Sum values with the same key path between two 2d arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, mapping

I need to merge and sum two 2d arrays so that values which share the same key-path are summed together.

```
$a = [[1, 2], [7, 2]];
$b = [[2, 3], [4, 9]];
```

My desired result:

```
[[3, 5], [11, 11]];
```

Comment: [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) would work nicely with your current issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best method for sum two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549045/best-method-for-sum-two-arrays)

Comment: The dupe target from Pratansyah is not appropriate for this question because the input data structures require deeper traversal.  It is certainly topically related though.

Answer (score 1):

**array_map & array_sum:**

```
$c[0] = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $a[0], $b[0]);

$c[1] = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $a[1], $b[1]);
```

**Further reading:**

- [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

**nested loop:**

```
$c = array();
for($x = 0; $x <= 1; $x++){
  for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++) {
    $c[$x][$i] = $a[$x][$i]+$b[$x][$i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach to nested loops can look like the following.  The variadic/spread dots (`...`) serve two purposes -- in `fn(...)` they accumulate an indeterminant number of values into a single variable as an array; or with `...$rows` the spread operator is expanding the indexed array as separate values as the input for the inner `array_map()` call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OXAOg))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$rows) => array_map(
            fn(...$cells) => array_sum($cells),
            ...$rows
        ),
        $a,
        $b
    )
);
```

---

If that syntax is too hard to follow, a classic nested `foreach()` loop will also do the job. In fact, it is better equipped to handle data sets where there may be element that doesn't have a correlating value in the other array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QCveB))

```
$result = $a;
foreach ($b as $i => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $j => $cell) {
        $result[$i][$j] = ($result[$i][$j] ?? 0) + $cell;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```