# Add a number to all the values of an interger array in Php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array:
Array
(
[1] => 4
[2] => 3
)

I want to +2 to all the elements of the array. So the final result will be:
Array
(
[1] => 6
[2] => 5
)

What is the shortest way with which I can achieve this?

I can iterate over the array through the loop and perform addition. But I was wondering if there is another way to achieve it.

Comment: When you say *shortest way*, in what sense do you mean, the least code, the quickest, the most obscure?

Comment: I meant the least code that would take lesser time to execute.

Comment: This might be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549249/11656450

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performance of foreach, array\_map with lambda and array\_map with static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function)

Comment: If you ask in terms of speed, `foreach` will be slightly faster than `array_map`. Link given by Nico Hasse gives a good explanation of the same with benchmarks.

Comment: I still find it interesting that all of the answers are still longer (and probably slower) than `foreach ( $array as &$v) $v+=2;` (although I wouldn't normally miss out the `{}`'s), but shows how little code this really needs.

Answer (score 2):

did you try:

```php
$newArray = array_map(function ($value) {
   return $value + 2;
}, $myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk) to do that.

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array_walk($array, function(&$item) { $item += 2; });
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Try this code it's work properly.`**

**onedimensional array time use below code**

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";        
    // onedimensional array time use below code
    $a = [4,3];
    echo "<br>A Input : ";
    print_r($a);
    $b = array_map(function($v){ return $v + 2 ; }, $a);
    echo "<br>B Result : ";
    print_r($b);
?>
```

**multidimensional array time use below code**

```
<?php 
    echo "<pre>";
    // multidimensional array time use below code
    $a1 = ["id" => 4,"name" => 3];
    echo "<br>A1 Input : ";
    print_r($a1);
    $b1 = array_map(function($v){ return $v + 2 ; }, array_values($a1));
    echo "<br>B1 Result : ";
    print_r($b1);
    
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it. For example, why do you need `array_values`?