# How do I compared 2 nested index lengths?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

First time posting here, I try to follow the questioning guides, sorry if I missed something.

I got a multidimensional array in PHP that do not have the same amount of results. Array[0] contains 6 while Array[1] only contains 4. here's an example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 122.7799987793
            [1] => 121.95999908447
            [2] => 121.90000152588
            [3] => 122.94000244141
            [4] => 122.18000030518
            [5] => 119.7200012207
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.705001831055
            [1] => 37.759998321533
            [2] => 37.889999389648
            [3] => 38.520000457764
        )

)
```

I managed to sum these 2 multidimentional arrays, using the following code:

```
$finalresult = array();

foreach($newarray[0] as $k => $v){
        $finalresult[$k] = array_sum(array_column($newarray, $k));  
}
```

So my result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 160.4850006104
            [1] => 159.719997406
            [2] => 159,7900009155
            [3] => 161,4600028992
            [4] => 122.18000030518
            [5] => 119.7200012207
        )

)
```

So the SUM worked fine for the first 4 values, but then the last two are not matching the pattern.

**What I am trying to achieve:**
In my database, I got an average number of each array. So basically what I would like the array_sum to do is:

```
array[0] + array[0]
array[1] + array[1]
array[2] + array[2]
array[3] + array[3]
array[4] + AVERAGE_VAR
array[5] + AVERAGE_VAR
```

To summarise: I am trying to achieve that the array with less values gets filled up with the average_variable_number which I pull from my MySQL database.

I tried a few things, but I can't wrap my head around it. I've been searching for a few days without any luck or tips where I have to look into.

Hope someone can show me an example of what the **foreach** function should look like to achieve the above.

Thank you a million in advance!!!

Comment: so in that 4 and 5 index is the average of 0,1,2,3 index? or just explain more bit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best method for sum two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549045/best-method-for-sum-two-arrays)

Comment: @OMiShah None of the answers there handle the case where the arrays have different lengths.

Comment: @OMiShah and Jerson, thanks for trying to help!  Barmar nailed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always just 2 arrays, you can loop up to the longer length, then test whether the element exists in both arrays, replacing a nonexistent element with the default value.

```
$len = max(count($newarray[0]), count($newarray[1]));
for ($i = 0; $i < len; $i++) {
    $val1 = array_key_exists($i, $newarray[0]) ? $newarray[0][$i] : $default;
    $val2 = array_key_exists($i, $newarray[1]) ? $newarray[1][$i] : $default;
    $finalresult[$i] = $val1 + $val2;
}
```

Comment: I can't cast a vote, because my reputation is not 15 points lol. But this did the trick @Barmar

I did have to debug it, line 2 you mentioned:


**$i < len;**


Should be **$i < $len**, but amazing job! Thanks!