# Sum value of common keys of PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
$data = array (
    "192.168.10.101" => array (
        "param1" => 80,
        "param2" => 3
    ),

    "192.168.10.99" => array (
        "param1" => 50,
        "param2" => 4
    )
);
```

I want to sum the value of common keys like sum `param1` of `192.168.10.101` with `param1` of `192.168.10.99`.

Comment: When i tried the method of  " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key " it  gives an error: Notice: Undefined index: param1 in D:\webdocuments\array.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: param2 in D:\webdocuments\array.php on line 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array_shift($array);
foreach ($array as $val) {
    foreach ($val as $key => $val) {
        $result[$key] += $val;
    }
}

print_r($result)

Array ( 
    [param1] => 130 
    [param2] => 7 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array(
    "192.168.10.101" => array (
        "param1" => 80,
        "param2" => 3
    ),

    "192.168.10.99" => array (
        "param1" => 50,
        "param2" => 4
    )
);
$sumArray = 0;
foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subArray) {
  if(isset($subArray['param1']))
    $sumArray +=$subArray['param1'];
}

print_r($sumArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "192.168.10.101" => array (
        "param1" => 80,
        "param2" => 3
    ),

    "192.168.10.99" => array (
        "param1" => 50,
        "param2" => 4
    )
);
$param_1=0;
$param_2=0;
foreach($data as $dat)
{
    $param_1+=$dat['param1'];
    $param_2+=$dat['param2'];

}

echo $param_1;
echo $param_2;
```

Comment: the array created is dynamic.

Comment: yes it is.. the loop will sum all the array key values

Answer (score 0):

```
$param_total = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    $param_total += $val['param1'];
}
echo $param_total;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like, (for the existence of key)

```
  if(isset($data['192.168.10.101']["param1"]) && isset($data['192.168.10.99']["param1"]))
  {
     $data['192.168.10.101']["param1"] += $data['192.168.10.99']["param1"];
  }
```