# Sum deep column values of an array with 3 levels of depth

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

How can I sum values of the key '*NILAI_ANGGARAN*'? Note that NILAI_ANGGARAN key is dynamic.

*array :*

```
[1350] => Array
    (
        [495] => Array
            (
                [NILAI_ANGGARAN] => 11000000
                [NILAI_PPN] => 1000000
                [PFK] => 0
                [TAPERUM] => 0
                [LAIN_LAIN] => 0
                [NILAI_PPH21] => 500000
                [NILAI_PPH22] => 0
                [NILAI_PPH23] => 0
                [NILAI_PPH4_2] => 0
                [DENDA] => 0
                [NILAI_BERSIH] => 10500000
            )

    )

[1300] => Array
    (
        [488] => Array
            (
                [NILAI_ANGGARAN] => 15000000
                [NILAI_PPN] => 1500000
                [PFK] => 0
                [TAPERUM] => 0
                [LAIN_LAIN] => 0
                [NILAI_PPH21] => 0
                [NILAI_PPH22] => 450000
                [NILAI_PPH23] => 300000
                [NILAI_PPH4_2] => 0
                [DENDA] => 0
                [NILAI_BERSIH] => 15750000
            )

    )
```

I've tried solution from [How to sum all column values in multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key) but it getting this error.

```
Undefined offset: 1350
```

Update :
*This is my desidred result :*

```
Array 
(
    [NILAI_ANGGARAN] => 26000000
    [NILAI_PPN] => 2500000
    [PFK] => 0
    [TAPERUM] => 0
    [LAIN_LAIN] => 0
    [NILAI_PPH21] => 500000
    [NILAI_PPH22] => 450000
    [NILAI_PPH23] => 300000
    [NILAI_PPH4_2] => 0
    [DENDA] => 0
    [NILAI_BERSIH] => 26250000
)
```

And this is the code I use :

```
$bruto = array();
foreach($array as $data => $key) {
    foreach($key as $k => $value) {
         foreach($value as $v => $isi) {
              $bruto[$k] += $value;
         }
    }
}
print_r($bruto);
```

Comment: What is your expected array? Post that too? What you have tried so far?

Comment: Also share your code which you are using from given link ?

Comment: What do you mean by `NILAI_ANGGARAN key is dynamic`? Does it change to something else?

Comment: Where is you code that creates the `Undefined offset: 1350` error? Also, post your desired result, based off the sample code you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Array:

```
$multi_dimentional_array = array (
'1350' => array
    (
        '495' => array
            (
                'NILAI_ANGGARAN' => 11000000,
                'NILAI_PPN' => 1000000,
                'PFK' => 0,
                'TAPERUM' => 0,
                'LAIN_LAIN' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH21' => 500000,
                'NILAI_PPH22' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH23' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH4_2' => 0,
                'DENDA' => 0,
                'NILAI_BERSIH' => 10500000
            )

    ),
'1300' => array
    (
        '488' => array
            (
                'NILAI_ANGGARAN' => 15000000,
                'NILAI_PPN' => 1500000,
                'PFK' => 0,
                'TAPERUM' => 0,
                'LAIN_LAIN' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH21' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH22' => 450000,
                'NILAI_PPH23' => 300000,
                'NILAI_PPH4_2' => 0,
                'DENDA' => 0,
                'NILAI_BERSIH' => 15750000
            )

    )
 );
```

Get sum values of the key 'NILAI_ANGGARAN' Code:

```
$NILAI_ANGGARAN_TOTAL = 0;
foreach( $multi_dimentional_array as $fkey=>$smarray )
{
    foreach ($smarray as $skey => $value) {
        // Empty check 
        if ( !empty( $value['NILAI_ANGGARAN'] ) ){
            $NILAI_ANGGARAN_TOTAL += $value['NILAI_ANGGARAN'];
        }       
    }

}
echo "Sum of NILAI_ANGGARAN is :{$NILAI_ANGGARAN_TOTAL}";
```

Result:`Sum of NILAI_ANGGARAN is :26000000`

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the multi-dimensional array to be $array.

You simply need to use nested loop here.

Try this:

```
$sum = 0;

foreach ($array as $arr) {

    foreach ($arr as $a) {

        $sum += $a['NILAI_ANGGARAN'];
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Answer (score 0):

You also need to **check if value with index `'NILAI_ANGGARAN'` exists**, otherwise PHP shows undefined offset error!

```
<?php
$array = array (
'1350' => array
    (
        '495' => array
            (
                'NILAI_ANGGARAN' => 11000000,
                'NILAI_PPN' => 1000000,
                'PFK' => 0,
                'TAPERUM' => 0,
                'LAIN_LAIN' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH21' => 500000,
                'NILAI_PPH22' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH23' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH4_2' => 0,
                'DENDA' => 0,
                'NILAI_BERSIH' => 10500000
            )

    ),
'1300' => array
    (
        '488' => array
            (
                'NILAI_ANGGARAN' => 15000000,
                'NILAI_PPN' => 1500000,
                'PFK' => 0,
                'TAPERUM' => 0,
                'LAIN_LAIN' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH21' => 0,
                'NILAI_PPH22' => 450000,
                'NILAI_PPH23' => 300000,
                'NILAI_PPH4_2' => 0,
                'DENDA' => 0,
                'NILAI_BERSIH' => 15750000
            )

    )
 );


$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $subarray)
{
    foreach($subarray as $subsubarrray)
    {
        if(isset($subsubarrray['NILAI_ANGGARAN'])) //check if isset
            $sum += $subsubarrray['NILAI_ANGGARAN'];
    }
}

var_dump($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use advance php for the same. Using `RecursiveArrayIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` it can be done easily:

```
$multi_dimentional_array = array (
    '1350' => array
    (
        '495' => array
        (
            'NILAI_ANGGARAN' => 11000000,
            'NILAI_PPN' => 1000000,
            'PFK' => 0,
            'TAPERUM' => 0,
            'LAIN_LAIN' => 0,
            'NILAI_PPH21' => 500000,
            'NILAI_PPH22' => 0,
            'NILAI_PPH23' => 0,
            'NILAI_PPH4_2' => 0,
            'DENDA' => 0,
            'NILAI_BERSIH' => 10500000
        )

    ),
    '1300' => array
    (
        '488' => array
        (
            'NILAI_ANGGARAN' => 15000000,
            'NILAI_PPN' => 1500000,
            'PFK' => 0,
            'TAPERUM' => 0,
            'LAIN_LAIN' => 0,
            'NILAI_PPH21' => 0,
            'NILAI_PPH22' => 450000,
            'NILAI_PPH23' => 300000,
            'NILAI_PPH4_2' => 0,
            'DENDA' => 0,
            'NILAI_BERSIH' => 15750000
        )

    )
);

$sum = 0;
$k_value = 'NILAI_ANGGARAN';
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($multi_dimentional_array));

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $k_value){
        $sum +=$value;
    }
}


echo "SUM of $k_value is $sum";
```

**Output**

```
SUM of NILAI_ANGGARAN is 26000000
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
$sum_arr = array();
foreach($main as $m_item){
    foreach($sub as $s_item){
        foreach($s_item as $skey => $value){
            $sum_arr[$skey] += $value;
        }
    }
}
```

use this code it will in `$sum_arr` is array of all element and its also in array format 
try this it will work 100% :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll offer a script to complete the task intended by your coding attempt. Because you first level keys are numeric strings, it will be safe to flatten your 3-level structure down to a 2-level structure via a "spread&merge" technique. This will not disrupt the keys in the 3rd level where the subsequent array column isolation will be performed.

Using `array_column()` on the temporary 2d array will avoid the need to check if a given column exists in each row.  Finally, use `array_sum()` on `array_column*)`'s 1d returned array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Z3LSd))

```
var_export(
    array_sum(
        array_column(
            array_merge(...$array),
            'NILAI_ANGGARAN'
        )
    )
);
// 26000000
```

---

If your actual intent is to accumulate totals for ALL columns of the deepest level, then flatten the array (as described above), then make iterated calls of `array_sum()` on each column of data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0ZgRB))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$col) => array_sum($col),
        ...array_merge(...$array)
    )
);

array (
  0 => 26000000,
  1 => 2500000,
  2 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 500000,
  6 => 450000,
  7 => 300000,
  8 => 0,
  9 => 0,
  10 => 26250000,
)
```

To preserve the column names in the result, it will probably be simplest to use nest loops, use the column names as associative keys in the result and ensure that there is always a values to add the current iteration's value to.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sotcJ))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $set) {
    foreach ($set as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
            $result[$k] = ($result[$k] ?? 0) + $v;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);

array (
  'NILAI_ANGGARAN' => 26000000,
  'NILAI_PPN' => 2500000,
  'PFK' => 0,
  'TAPERUM' => 0,
  'LAIN_LAIN' => 0,
  'NILAI_PPH21' => 500000,
  'NILAI_PPH22' => 450000,
  'NILAI_PPH23' => 300000,
  'NILAI_PPH4_2' => 0,
  'DENDA' => 0,
  'NILAI_BERSIH' => 26250000,
)
```