# How to sum values of same key in array associative

Tags: php, arrays, sum, key, associative

I'm not getting this right when trying to sum values of keys that are same within an associative array. I thought it's gonna be easy task, but it ain't the case so please...

I'm expecting following result:

```
 1 -->(7) 
2 -->(14)
```

Here's the array:

```
 $array = array( 1=>4, 2=>8, 1=>3, 2=>6, );
```

Here's what i tried since:

```
$sum= array();
```

foreach ($array as $key => $value){ $sum[$key] += $value;}
print_r($sum);

Anyway, there's no loop performed at all, since it's returning this result,

```
Array ( [1] => 3 [2] => 6 );
```

and an error,

```
 Undefined offset: 1
```

I thought maybe there's a PHP function to handle it, but I'll be glad for any help.

Comment: Something i didn't know. Just found a different approach based on what you said and it works great, thank you for helping

Comment: This question is unclear because the sample input is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is impossible. Arrays cannot have duplicate keys:

```
php > $arr = array(1=>2, 1=>500);
php > var_dump($arr);
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(500)  // hey! where'd "2" go?
}
```

If you want to store multiple values in a single key, then that key has to point to an array:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[1] = array(1, 500);
var_dump($arr);
php > var_dump($arr);
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(500)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thank u for your support. Based on your advise and that from @Paul Crovella,  i tried a different approach trying to isolate each key within an array. Got so well the desired result, but still the persistent   error:  Undefined offset: 1   Undefined offset: 7 on each key... What i did looks like this:                                                  $arr = array( array(1=> 500), array(1=> 20), array(7=> 5));       

$arraySum = array();

foreach ($arr as $key => $arrChilds) {
 
  foreach ($arrChilds as $key2 => $value) {
    $arraySum[$key2]+= $value;
 }
}print_r($arraySum);

Comment: The second approach worked fine since i found out on stackoverflow how to get rid of the notices. Just wanna say thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key/9938193#9938193