# Getting total from mysql query with array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code and i would like to get total combination of all categories

my code so far

```
     for ($k = 0; $k < 4; $k++) {   

     $result= $DB->query("SELECT total FROM ".$DB->prefix("mystat")." WHERE year='$year' AND category='$categoryname[$k]'");
               $row = $DB->fetchArray($result);
           $total=$row['total'];   
echo $total++;
     }
```

let say i have this data

```
A - 1
B - 2
C - 3
```

my current output

```
123
```

my desired output

```
6
```

How do i correct this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key  please have a look at this . this may help you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are doing echo in loop. And also you logic is wrong. change your code like:

```
$total = 0;
for ($k = 0; $k < 4; $k++) {
    $result= $DB->query("SELECT total FROM ".$DB->prefix("mystat")." WHERE year='$year' AND category='$categoryname[$k]'");
    $row = $DB->fetchArray($result);
    $total +=$row['total'];   
}
echo $total; // DO echo here
```

Also if you don't need categories and total separately and only need sum of all then its better to use `SUM` with `group by` category in sql.

Comment: Thank you very much