# Adding values two arrays with same keys

Tags: php

How can I sum values of two arrays with same keys. Example:

```
$a = ('ox' => '5'; 'wow'=>'6')
$b = ('ox' => '15'; 'wow'=>'4')
```

Desired result

```
$c = ('ox' => '20'; 'wow'=>'10')
```

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried?  iterating across one object's keys and adding in the other's values would be a start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum values of the array of the same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$c = [];
foreach($a as $key => $a_){
    $c[$key] = $a_ + $b[$key];
}
```