# sum and merge duplicate value from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to sum the value of `movements` while keeping an unique value  for `day` on the same array.

The base array:

```
array (607)
0 => array (2)
    day => "11" (2)
    movements => 1
1 => array (2)
    day => "11" (2)
    movements => 1
2 => array (2)
    day => "11" (2)
    movements => 1
3 => array (2)
    day => "12" (2)
    movements => 1
4 => array (2)
    day => "12" (2)
    movements => 1
5 => array (2)
    day => "12" (2)
    movements => 1

[...]
```

The result I am expecting (for each `day` sum `movements`):

```
array (607)
    0 => array (2)
        day => "11" (2)
        movements => 3
    1 => array (2)
        day => "12" (2)
        movements => 3    
    [...]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: What I have tried so far :

- [sum-array-values-of-the-same-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/sum-array-values-of-the-same-key?noredirect=1&lq=1):  it also sum `day`which is not what I am expecting.
- my own code:

  ```
  $arr1 = $stats['data']['vhc']; // contain ['day'] and ['movements']
  $arr2 = $data['vhc']; // contain ['day'] and ['movements']
  $sum = [];

  if (!empty($arr1)) {
      $result = [];
      foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
          if (isset($arr2[$key]['day']) && $arr2[$key]['day'] == $value['day']) {
              $result['day'] = $value['day'];
              $result['movements'] = $value['movements'] + $arr2[$key]['movements'];
          }
          array_push($sum, $result);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do with `foreach()` and [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($array as $arr){
  $final_array[$arr['day']]['day'] = $arr['day'];
  $final_array[$arr['day']]['movements'] = (isset($final_array[$arr['day']]['movements']))? $final_array[$arr['day']]['movements']+$arr['movements'] : $arr['movements'];    
}
$final_array = array_values($final_array);

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/957326

Answer (score 1):

This method will not bother overwriting result array data with the same value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/e6V3Y))

```
$array=[
    ['day'=>'11','movements'=>'1'],
    ['day'=>'11','movements'=>'1'],
    ['day'=>'11','movements'=>'1'],
    ['day'=>'12','movements'=>'1'],
    ['day'=>'12','movements'=>'1'],
    ['day'=>'12','movements'=>'1']
];
foreach($array as $row){  // iterate all rows
    if(!isset($result[$row['day']])){  // if first occurrence of day...
        $result[$row['day']]=$row;     // save the full row with day as the temporary key
    }else{                                    // if not the first occurrence of day...
        $result[$row['day']]['movements']+=$row['movements'];  // add movements value
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'day' => '11',
    'movements' => 3,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'day' => '12',
    'movements' => 3,
  ),
)
```