# How to subtract all column values in multi-dimensional array in Php?

Tags: php

How can I subtract all the columns values? My array is like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [web_traffic] => 442
            [form_users] => 131
            [date] => 20181004
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [web_traffic] => 102
            [form_users] => 15
            [date] => 20181003
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [web_traffic] => 387
            [form_users] => 97
            [date] => 20181002
        )
)
```

I need to subtract the each column(except date & id) and get the result based on date(Ascending order). For example 20181004 means 4th October 2018. My output should like the below

```
Array
(
    [web_traffic] => -152
    [form_users] => -49
)
```

My code took reference from [How to sum all column values in multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-all-column-values-in-multi-dimensional-array)

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
        unset($value[ 'id' ]);
        $time = date('Ymd', strtotime($value[ 'date' ]));
        if (in_array($time, $dates)) {
            $value[ 'date' ] = $time;
            foreach ($value as $key => $secondValue) {
                if ( !isset($output[ $key ])) {
                    $output[ $key ] = 0;
                }
                $output[ $key ] -= $secondValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also show us the code you have written to attempt to do this please

Comment: Subtract **what from what .... giving what**?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Edited the code

Comment: And the `$dates` array looks like what?

Comment: It looks like 2018-10-04 00:00:00

Comment: Then `$time` is never going to look like one of those dates as it has no time! try `$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($value[ 'date' ]));`

Comment: I want to subtract the value of 'web_traffic' & 'form_users'. The date is not very important.

Comment: It is if you use it in this statement `if (in_array($time, $dates)) {`

Comment: I did the same. Still it shows incorrect result

Comment: So what result is it showing?

Comment: It shows 'web_traffic' => -931 instead of -157

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP `array_reduce()` and `array_column()` like this:

```
$initial_array = array(array('id'           => 1,
                     'web_traffic'  => 442,
                     'form_users'   => 131,
                     'date'         => 20181004),
               array('id'           => 2,
                     'web_traffic'  => 102,
                     'form_users'   => 15,
                     'date'         => 20181003),
               array('id'           => 3,
                     'web_traffic'  => 387,
                     'form_users'   => 97,
                     'date'         => 20181002));

function sum($carry, $item)
    {
        $carry -= $item;
        return $carry;
    }

$web_traffic  = array_column($initial_array, "web_traffic");
$form_users = array_column($initial_array, "form_users");
$date = array_column($initial_array, "date");


array_multisort($date, SORT_ASC, $form_users, SORT_DESC,  $initial_array);


$result_array = Array(
            "web_traffic" => array_reduce(array_column($initial_array, "web_traffic"), "sum",2*$initial_array[0]['web_traffic']),
            "form_users" => array_reduce(array_column($initial_array, "form_users"), "sum",2*$initial_array[0]['form_users'])
        );

print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: Output is : `array([web_traffic] => -931, [form_users] => -243)`. This is not what OP expected

Comment: Yes, but how do you arrive at the expected result by subtracting. Please explain.

Comment: By sorting first by date, ASC, as stated in question *get the result based on date(Ascending order)*

Comment: Does the sort affect the result? Since you going to subtract everything, doesn't the sorting become redundant?

Comment: `387 - 102 - 442 == -157`. The operation isn't supposed to be `-442 - 102 - 387`.

Comment: Your answer work if you can exclude the oldest date from the `array_reduce(...)` and adding this result to the oldest result `(-442 - 102) + 387`

Comment: I hope I got it now

Comment: Yes I got the expected results, upvoting

Comment: Wow, clap for me, haha

Comment: We could user rsort($data), instead of array_multisort & the logic

Comment: That is true @Ashish

Answer (score 0):

I would first sort the array using [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) in example.

Sorting first, because that can be tricky to substract in 1 loop the oldest datas to the newers one.

Separating intentions provide a cleaner code, easier to maintain.

The dates don't need to be converted into a `date`. The string is well formatted and can be used as is in a comparison and a sort. `"20170101" < "20180101"`, `"20180101" < "20181001"` and `"20181002" < "20181004"`

When done, I'll save the first values as initial values to be used in substract.

Then, loop the sorted array and substract the `'web_traffic'` and `'form_users'` to the initial values.

```
$datas = array(array('id'           => 1,
                     'web_traffic'  => 442,
                     'form_users'   => 131,
                     'date'         => 20181004),
               array('id'           => 2,
                     'web_traffic'  => 102,
                     'form_users'   => 15,
                     'date'         => 20181003),
               array('id'           => 3,
                     'web_traffic'  => 387,
                     'form_users'   => 97,
                     'date'         => 20181002));

//If needed, you can backup the original array, because usort() will modify it.
$backUpDatas = $datas;

//Sort
usort($datas, function ($arr1, $arr2)
{
    if (isset($arr1['date']) && isset($arr2['date']))
    {
        if ($arr1['date'] == $arr2['date'])
            return (0);
        return (($arr1['id'] > $arr2['id']) ? (-1) : (1));
    }
});

//Initial values
$finalValues['web_traffic'] = $datas[0]['web_traffic'];
$finalValues['form_users'] = $datas[0]['form_users'];

//Substract
foreach ($datas as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key > 0)
    {
        if (isset($value['web_traffic']))
            $finalValues['web_traffic'] -= $value['web_traffic'];
        if (isset($value['form_users']))
            $finalValues['form_users'] -= $value['form_users'];
    }
}

var_dump($finalValues);
```

Output :

```
array (size=2)
  'web_traffic' => int -157
  'form_users' => int -49
```