# how to combine PHP arrays 2D and convert to array 1D with operator?

Tags: php, arrays

How to convert the 2D arrays to 1D array in PHP? Help me Please..

```
$array[0]['B0001'] + $array[2]['B0001'] + $array[more]['B0001'];
```

if the array key is equal (same), just addition (plus) the value of array and remove duplicate array key...

and convert 2D array like this :

PHP: 5.6.36 - Example Result array 2D, var_dump($array);

**before :**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["B0001"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["B0003"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["B0004"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["B0002"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["B0001"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["B0003"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [more]=>
  array(more) {
    ["B0001"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["B0003"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["more"]=>
    string(more) "xx"
  }
}
```

**after :**

```
array(1) {
    ["B0001"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["B0003"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["B0004"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["B0002"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["more"]=>
    string(more) "xx"
  }
```

Thank You!!

Comment: You may want to look at [array-reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

Comment: Nested `foreach` loops should work.

Comment: Thank You @Barmar i will try it..

Comment: I've added an array_reduce solution to that page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163169/3392762

Answer (score 0):

**solved!**

```
$sumArray = array();

foreach ($array as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
    $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
  }
}
```

**Source:**
[How to sum all column values in multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-all-column-values-in-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: Just link to your preferred answer.

Comment: done! thank you sir :)