# How to sum array by value?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I sum this array by value? Just sum value of [jumlah] group by [Kondisi].

```
Array 
( 
[0] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [Kondisi] => one
        [jumlah] => 2
    ) 
[1] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [Kondisi] => two 
        [jumlah] => 3
    ) 
[2] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [Kondisi] => three
        [jumlah] => 4
    ) 
[3] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [Kondisi] => one
        [jumlah] => 3
    ) 
[4] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [Kondisi] => two
        [jumlah] => 1
    ) 
[5] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [Kondisi] => three
        [jumlah] => 3
    ) 
)
```

I have try [How to sum all column values in multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-all-column-values-in-multi-dimensional-array), but didn't help.

I want output like this:

```
Array 
( 
[0] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [Kondisi] => one 
        [jumlah] => 5
    ) 
[1] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [Kondisi] => two
        [jumlah] => 4
    ) 
[2] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [Kondisi] => three
        [jumlah] => 7
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample code can be:

```
$sums = [];

// `$objects` is your initial array 
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    // here we check if key `$object->Kondisi` exists in `$sums` array
    if (empty($sums[$object->Kondisi])) {
        // if `no` - this is new object, store it as is
        $sums[$object->Kondisi] = $object;
    } else {
        // if `yes` - add `jumlah` value to existing `jumlah` property
        $sums[$object->Kondisi]->jumlah += $object->jumlah;
    }
}

// use `array_values` to get 0-indexed array
print_r(array_values($sums));
```