# How to get sum of array values according to some index (non-sorted)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, array-sum

I want the sum of `monthly_rental` and `arc` if the `month` and `full_name` are the same in one array.

Input Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 521
                    [full_name] => Nilesh chauhan
                    [monthly_rental] => 15000
                    [arc] => 180000
                    [month] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1549
                    [full_name] => Ritesh shah
                    [monthly_rental] => 14166.666666667
                    [arc] => 170000
                    [month] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 589
                    [full_name] => Gajanan satpute
                    [monthly_rental] => 14166.666666667
                    [arc] => 170000
                    [month] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 521
                    [full_name] => Nilesh chauhan
                    [monthly_rental] => 13333.333333333
                    [arc] => 160000
                    [month] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1549
                    [full_name] => Ritesh shah
                    [monthly_rental] => 11250
                    [arc] => 135000
                    [month] => 2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 521
                    [full_name] => Nilesh chauhan
                    [monthly_rental] => 7500
                    [arc] => 90000
                    [month] => 2
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1549
                    [full_name] => Ritesh shah
                    [monthly_rental] => 7000
                    [arc] => 84000
                    [month] => 2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1549
                    [full_name] => Ritesh shah
                    [monthly_rental] => 35833.333333333
                    [arc] => 430000
                    [month] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1549
                    [full_name] => Ritesh shah
                    [monthly_rental] => 14166.666666667
                    [arc] => 170000
                    [month] => 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 521
                    [full_name] => Nilesh chauhan
                    [monthly_rental] => 13333.333333333
                    [arc] => 160000
                    [month] => 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 521
                    [full_name] => Nilesh chauhan
                    [monthly_rental] => 8750
                    [arc] => 105000
                    [month] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 589
                    [full_name] => Gajanan satpute
                    [monthly_rental] => 7500
                    [arc] => 90000
                    [month] => 3
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1549
                    [full_name] => Ritesh shah
                    [monthly_rental] => 6493.3333333333
                    [arc] => 77920
                    [month] => 3
                )
        )
)
```

There are 6 sub-arrays in 1st and 2-nd indexes, I want the sum of `0,1,5 (Ritesh Shah, Month 2)` array and make them unique. Same as this I have a long list of the array but I will manage them all if any of you just suggest to me how to get sum value of this array.

OUTPUT That I want :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 521
                    [full_name] => Nilesh chauhan
                    [monthly_rental] => 15000
                    [arc] => 180000
                    [month] => 1
                )

        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1549
                    [full_name] => Ritesh shah
                    [monthly_rental] => 32416.66
                    [arc] => 389000
                    [month] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 589
                    [full_name] => Gajanan satpute
                    [monthly_rental] => 14166.666666667
                    [arc] => 170000
                    [month] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 521
                    [full_name] => Nilesh chauhan
                    [monthly_rental] => 20833.33
                    [arc] => 250000
                    [month] => 2
                )

        )
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum all column values in multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-all-column-values-in-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: No in this I have a different name and when i used your suggested question logic it gives the sum of all value not that I wanted.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you already tried, and explain what exactly the problem with that was. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @04FS Sir, I have spent my second half solving this, this is not what you are thinking.

Comment: Then please _show_ what you have tried! Otherwise I don’t know how we are supposed to consider this anything but _pretense_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply this function and retrieve your expected output:

```
function getCustomMonoRecords($data){

    $res = [];

    foreach($data as $m=>$ar){
        $res[$m] = [];   
        $tmp = []; 
        $i = 0;
        foreach($ar as $ind=>$rec){
            if(!array_key_exists($rec['id'],$tmp)) {
                $tmp[$rec['id']] = $i;  
                $res[$m][$i] = $rec;
                $i++;
            } else {
                $in = $tmp[$rec['id']];
                $res[$m][$in]['monthly_rental'] += $rec['monthly_rental'];
                $res[$m][$in]['arc'] += $rec['arc'];
            }
        } 
    }
    return $res;
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YEjft)**

Or a little bit different:

```
function getCustomMonoRecords2($data){

    $res = [];

    foreach($data as $m=>$ar){
        $res[$m] = [];     
        foreach($ar as $ind=>$rec){ 
            if(!isset($res[$m][$rec['id']])){
                $res[$m][$rec['id']] = $rec;
            } else {
                $res[$m][$rec['id']]['monthly_rental'] += $rec['monthly_rental'];
                $res[$m][$rec['id']]['arc'] += $rec['arc'];
            } 
        } 
        $res[$m] = array_values($res[$m]);
    } 
    return $res;
}
```

**[Demo2](https://3v4l.org/4VXhv)**

Comment: Thank you sir, both functions are working perfectly.