# Codeigniter sum column of the same id

Tags: codeigniter

Hello guys I am trying to insert data into my database. Some values contain the same id. I want to sum during insertion and not add a new row:

```
 if ($q->num_rows() >0) 
 {

        $this->db->where('student_id',$id);

        $this->db->set('mark_obtained', ' mark_obtained+ '. $obtained_marks['mark_obtained'], FALSE);
        $this->db->update('position' , array('mark_obtained' => $obtained_marks , 'student_id' =>$row['student_id'] , 'exam_id'=> $row['exam_id'],'subject_id' =>$row['subject_id'],'section_id'=>$row['section_id'], 'class_id'=>$row['class_id']));
  } 
  else {

        $this->db->insert('position' , array('mark_obtained' => $obtained_marks , 'student_id' =>$row['student_id'] , 'exam_id'=> $row['exam_id'],'subject_id' =>$row['subject_id'],'section_id'=>$row['section_id'], 'class_id'=>$row['class_id']));

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Before going to Query you should sum the same id value in array then pass the data into Your Query check this link to

[Sum the array having same keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-all-column-values-in-multi-dimensional-array)