# How to group and sum subarray items in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

I have N arrays. with n grade_items subarrays.
just like this.

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:10 [
    "id" => 9
    "course_id" => 6
    "semester_id" => 2
    "name" => "Assignment"
    "total_score" => 10
    "grade_items" => array:1 [
      0 => array:7 [
        "id" => 5
        "gradelist_id" => 9
        "student_course_id" => 11
        "score" => 8
        "created_at" => "2020-04-21T03:31:20.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-04-21T20:04:10.000000Z"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:10 [
    "id" => 10
    "course_id" => 6
    "semester_id" => 2
    "name" => "Pop Quiz"
    "total_score" => 20
    "grade_items" => array:1 [
      0 => array:7 [
        "id" => 6
        "gradelist_id" => 10
        "student_course_id" => 11
        "score" => null
        "created_at" => "2020-04-22T00:11:17.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-04-22T00:11:17.000000Z"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I am trying to add each grade_item subarray from each array where the student_course_id is the same. Where there is only one grade_item and no other one with the same student_course_id, then it returns just that one value instead of a sum.

I have gone through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-all-column-values-in-multi-dimensional-array/1496704)

But it just messed up the logic in my head further. I've been at this for weeks.

When I add the scores from each grade_item, i want to put that value into another model say "result_model" that would look like:

```
result_item [
    "id" => 1,
    "student_course_id" => 11,
    "score" => 15 //total of grade_items from all arrays where the student_course_id's were the same
];
```

Help!

Comment: where does the id come from the result model - i understand student_course_id and score (sum of same course ids ) but didn't get id

Comment: It's automatically generated when I create a new instance of the model. I just gave a structure to what it should look like after the model is saved.

Comment: Like when it checks the first grade_item in the first array, It would search through other arrays(not that sub array), for other grade_items with the same student_course_id and add the scores together. Then create a new result_item with the student_course_id and the computed score.

Comment: asking to clarify, at the end of the day; you want the sum of scores which are grouped by student_course_id right ?

Comment: yeah, exactly. but across the arrays not just within the subarrays.

Comment: yeah, exactly. but across the arrays not just within the subarrays. By the way, the student_course_id's within a subarray are always unique. There can't be two items with same student_course_id. I hope this gives it some clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to regroup the current information to receive the sum of grades. It seems the the information comes form a databases, so why don't you GROUP BY and sum on database level?

Anyway. Here's an approach. Start by keeping a map of `student_course_id` => `score`. First it will be empty: `$map = []`;

Then start iterating through the whole structure e.g. `foreach ($data as $row`. For each row, you need to check all the corresponding `grade_items` e.g. `foreach ($row['grade_items'] as $gradeItem)`. Now you need to check whether the `student_course_id` from the grade item is present into the mapping.

If it's not present, create it with starting value of zero e.g.

```
if (!key_exists($gradeItem['student_course_id'], $map)) { 
    $map[$gradeItem['student_course_id']] = 0;
}
```

Once you ensure that the `student_course_id` is present, you can just add to the previous value the current score => `$map[$gradeItem['student_course_id']] += $gradeItem['score']`.

Comment: Hmmm! this is a very good approach. I'd try it out now and get back to you. What you said about regrouping it and summing on database level got my attention too. I will look into that also.

Comment: This worked! So I took your advice and regrouped  and summed on database level. 
So I got all the ```grade_items``` from the arrays I was interested in and groupedBy the ```student_course_id``` then looped through each group and got the sum, then I instantiated the ```result_item``` model and saved the score as the sum of the group.

Comment: So my grouping looked like this
```
array:1 [
  11 => array:2 [
    0 => array:7 [
      "id" => 5
      "gradelist_id" => 9
      "student_course_id" => 11
      "score" => 8
    ]
    1 => array:7 [
      "id" => 6
      "gradelist_id" => 10
      "student_course_id" => 11
      "score" => 0
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: then I did this.

```
foreach ($grade_items as $key => $grade_item) {
            $sum = $grade_item->sum('score');

            $result_item = new ResultItem();
            $result_item->student_course_id = $key;
            $result_item->score = $sum;
            $result_item->save();

}

```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample data i used

```
$array = [
        [
            'id' => 9,
            'course_id' => 6,
            'semester_id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Assignment',
            'total_score' => 10,
            'grade_items' => [
                [
                    'id' => 5,
                    'gradelist_id' => 9,
                    'student_course_id' => 11,
                    'score' => 8,
                    'created_at' => '2020-04-21T03:31:20.000000Z',
                    'updated_at' => '2020-04-21T20:04:10.000000Z',
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 5,
                    'gradelist_id' => 9,
                    'student_course_id' => 15,
                    'score' => 15,
                    'created_at' => '2020-04-21T03:31:20.000000Z',
                    'updated_at' => '2020-04-21T20:04:10.000000Z',
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            'id' => 10,
            'course_id' => 6,
            'semester_id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Pop Quiz',
            'total_score' => 20,
            'grade_items' => [
                [
                    'id' => 6,
                    'gradelist_id' => 10,
                    'student_course_id' => 11,
                    'score' => 21,
                    'created_at' => '2020-04-22T00:11:17.000000Z',
                    'updated_at' => '2020-04-22T00:11:17.000000Z',
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 6,
                    'gradelist_id' => 10,
                    'student_course_id' => 23,
                    'score' => 15,
                    'created_at' => '2020-04-22T00:11:17.000000Z',
                    'updated_at' => '2020-04-22T00:11:17.000000Z',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

and here is the code;

```
    $id = 0;

    return collect($array)
        ->flatMap(function ($item){
            return $item['grade_items'];
        })
        ->groupBy('student_course_id')
        ->transform(function ($subItems, $courseId) use (&$id) {
            $id++;

            return [
                'id' => $id,
                'student_course_id' => $courseId,
                'score' => $subItems->sum('score')
            ];
        })
        ->values()
        ->toArray();
```

here is the result;

```
        [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'student_course_id' => 11,
                'score' => 29,
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'student_course_id' => 15,
                'score' => 15,
            ],
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'student_course_id' => 23,
                'score' => 15,
            ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sum()` function. You can loop through the array, and do any checks you need, like if it is not Null etc, and pluck() it and then sum() it.

Comment: Doing this would only give me access to the subarray in an array and not across all arrays.
I want to sum values from the two arrays, not within the subarray. 

Like. sum all the grade_items in all arrays where the student_course_id's are equal.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest recursivity approach?

```
<?php 
    function rec_sum_grades(&$array_grades, &$sum = 0){
      $sum += $array_grades['total_score'];
      if(!empty($array_grades['grade_items'])){
      $this->rec_sum_grades($array_grades['grade_items'], $sum);
    }
  }
  rec_sum_grades($array_grades, $sum);
  echo $sum;
?>
```

Comment: Hmmm... the issue here is that it would add across grade_items with different student_course_id's instead of items with the same student_course_id. But after grouping the grade_items by student_course_id, then this would work for me. Thank you!