# PHP Sum value of specific key with the same ID inside n numbers of arrays in array

Tags: php

I want to sum the value of one key (qty) if has the same ID of n numbers of arrays inside an array,
in this example I have only 2 arrays but I could have 1000

```
           $a = array(
            array(
                "id"=>1, 
                "qty"=>2
            ), 
            array(
                "id"=>1, 
                "qty"=>4
            )
            ...n arrays
            );
```

I want the result like this...

```
            $b = array(
            array(
                "id"=>1, 
                "qty"=>6
            ));
```

I want a function to pass variable $a with n numbers of arrays and returned $b. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum all column values in multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-all-column-values-in-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved

```
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $id = $v['id'];
        $result[$id][] = $v['quantity'];
    }

$new = array();
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $new[] = array('id' => $key, 'quanity' => array_sum($value));
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new);
?>
```