# Calculate the sum of multidimensional array with same index or different indexes

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

In the multidimensional array like the example given below, how to calculate values with the same index and store them in a new array:

```
$a = array(
    0 => array(
        "a" =>  12,
        "b" =>  78,
        "c" =>  5,
        "d" =>  5,
    ),
    1 => array(
        "a" =>  5,
        "b" =>  12,
        "c" =>  7,
        "d" =>  16,
    ),
    2 => array(
        "a" =>  13,
        "b" =>  79,
        "c" =>  12,
        "d" =>  16,
    ),
    3 => array(
        "a" =>  4,
        "b" =>  1,
        "c" =>  6,
        "d" =>  4,
    )
);
```

We should get an array like this:

```
$sum = array (
    "a"   =>  35,
    "b"   =>  170,
    "c"   =>  30,
    "d"   =>  41,
);
```

Or like this:

```
$sum = array (
    0   =>  35,
    1   =>  170,
    2   =>  30,
    3   =>  41,
);
```

Comment: [How to sum all column values in multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-all-column-values-in-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: I have seen the question I can't get my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following example:

```
$sum = [];

foreach($a as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($sum[$key])) $sum[$key] = 0;
        $sum[$key] += $value;
    }
}

print_r($sum);
```

If all items have the same keys:

```
$sum = array_fill_keys(array_keys(reset($a)), 0);

foreach($sum as $key => &$value) {
    $value = array_sum(array_column($a, $key));
}

print_r($sum);
```

Comment: I have used it but I get an error like: "Undefined Index: A"

Comment: Look this [fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34beb72273003136409dca6d567bff598b6aa812) Works with your described array `$a`.

Comment: Thanks, this one is working. I got it.

Comment: Yes it is working with arrays with the same indexes

Comment: If we have different indexes in a multidimensional array, at that time what should we do?

Comment: Like this:http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cac9dfb488710c59c339126257668f45862d0000

Comment: Then this would be the previous code: [fiddle](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b0fd83eb544ae767b6e53127dd5a0212ba35278). To sort result by key `ksort($sum);`.