# Group row data from a 2d array by one column and separately sum 2 other columns in each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have the following array:

```
[ 
    ['id' => 1, 'uid' => 50, 'sum1' => 1, 'sum2' => 2],
    ['id' => 2, 'uid' => 50, 'sum1' => 2, 'sum2' => 4],
    ['id' => 3, 'uid' => 51, 'sum1' => 3, 'sum2' => 5],
]
```

As you can see, on some of those indexes, [uid] is the same. The length and data of the array is dynamic.

What I need to do is merge the indexes that have the same value for [uid] and sum the values of the non-identifying keys.

Desired result:

```
[
    ['id' => 2, 'uid' => 50, 'sum1' => 3, 'sum2' => 6],
    ['id' => 3, 'uid' => 51, 'sum1' => 3, 'sum2' => 5],
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum all column values in multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-all-column-values-in-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: Create a new array, iterate over the original one, for each item check if an object having same uid is present (using array_column and array_search)... if present increment values, otherwise append. Not difficult.

Comment: Actually, B001, it dosen't because inthat example are all idexes to be summed up or in my case, i need to sum only the matching keys.

Comment: @SalmanA, that is a good idea. i'll try to implemet that. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this way,

```
<?php
$mainArray = [ 
    0 => Array
    (
        'id' => 1,
        'uid' => 50,
        'sum1' => 1,
        'sum2' => 2
    ),
    1 => Array
    (
        'id' => 2,
        'uid' => 50,
        'sum1' => 2,
        'sum2' => 4
    ),
    2 => Array
    (
        'id' => 3,
        'uid' => 51,
        'sum1' => 3,
        'sum2' => 5
    )
];
$newArray=[];
foreach ($mainArray as $value) {
    if(!array_key_exists($value['uid'], $newArray)){
        // Store first time
        $newArray[$value['uid']] = $value;
    }else{
        // Already exist, then sum and replace it
        $newArray[$value['uid']]['id'] = $value['id'];
        $newArray[$value['uid']]['sum1'] += $value['sum1'];// Sum with previous value
        $newArray[$value['uid']]['sum2'] += $value['sum2'];// Sum with previous value
    }
}
$newArray = array_values($newArray);// Reset indexes, Start the array index with zero
print_r($newArray);// To see the output
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [uid] => 50
            [sum1] => 3
            [sum2] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [uid] => 51
            [sum1] => 3
            [sum2] => 5
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct. Actually, i solved the problem using something similar:

```
$sumArray = Array();
foreach ($array1 as $item){

        if(isset($sumArray[$item['uid']])){          
          $sumArray[$item['idPartener']]['sum1'] += $item['sum1'];
          $sumArray[$item['idPartener']]['sum2'] += $item['sum2'];

        }else{          
          $sumArray[$item['uid']] = Array(
            'id' => $item['id'],             
            'sum1' => $item['sum1'],
            'sum2' => $item['sum2'] ,
          );
        }

    }
```

Thanks  all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid needing to re-index the array after grouping, push a reference into the result array every time a unique `uid` value is encountered.  That reference should carry the whole row as the base value.  If the same `uid` is encountered again, add the `sum1` and `sum2` values to the reference's respective column values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Fpe8P))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($ref[$row['uid']])) {
        $ref[$row['uid']] = $row;
        $result[] =& $ref[$row['uid']];
        continue;
    }
    $ref[$row['uid']]['sum1'] += $row['sum1'];
    $ref[$row['uid']]['sum2'] += $row['sum2'];
}
var_export($result);
```